# calculate working hours for current week in django

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-views, django-forms

let us consider start time, end time and Break time as

**models.py**

```
class Records(TimeStampedModel):
   date = models.DateField()
   start_time = models.TimeField(default='08:30')
   end_time = models.TimeField(default='08:30')
   break_time = models.FloatField(default=0.5, help_text="(Hrs)")
```

**views.py**

```
def record_working hours(request):
    records = Records.objects.filter(created_by__client=request.user.client)
    now = timezone.now()
    today = timezone.now().date()
    week_start = today - timedelta(days=(today.weekday()))
    date_list = [week_start + timedelta(days=x) for x in range(5)]
    week_last = date_list[-1]
    working_time = records.filter(date__gte=week_start,date__lte=week_last)

    for record in records:
        work_hours = record.start_time  - record.end_time - record.break_time

    return redirect(reverse('record_list'))
```

Hear i need to calculate total working hours for current week but i am getting the error as " type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime'" and when i print my start time, end time and break time i am getting as

```
 start_time = datetime.time(8, 30)
 end_time = datetime.time(18, 30)
 break_time = 0.5
```

And also calculate total working hours for that week of all records

Comment: Include more details e.g. the whole view and/or the model

Comment: Python time objects cannot be used to calculate the difference.  Datetime objects are needed here.